# C# LINQ - Loop through list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a test LINQ list below

```
List<test> test=new List<test>();
test.Add(new test("Bakery","bakery@store.com","Donut"));
test.Add(new test("Bakery","bakery@store.com","Bagel"));
test.Add(new test("Bakery","bakery@store.com","Cake"));
test.Add(new test("Produce","produce@store.com","Apple"));
test.Add(new test("Dairy","dairy@store.com","Milk"));
test.Add(new test("Dairy","dairy@store.com","Yogurt"));
```

Some departments have more than 1 item.  How can loop through the list and send 1 email to each department/email address with the item(s).  Send 1 email to bakery@store.com with Donut, Bagel, Cake in the body. Send 1 email to produce@store.com with Apple in the body. Send 1 email to dairy@store.com with Milk, Yogurt in the body

I don't need help with the email part, just need help to loop through the list and get items per department.  Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Important terminology note: *"LINQ list"* is not a thing. It's just a list. LINQ is a querying mechanism. A "linked list" is a kind of list, but that's not what this list is.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<test> test=new List<test>();
test.Add(new test("Bakery","bakery@store.com","Donut"));
test.Add(new test("Bakery","bakery@store.com","Bagel"));
test.Add(new test("Bakery","bakery@store.com","Cake"));
test.Add(new test("Produce","produce@store.com","Apple"));
test.Add(new test("Dairy","dairy@store.com","Milk"));
test.Add(new test("Dairy","dairy@store.com","Yogurt"));

foreach (var group in test.GroupBy(x=> x.Department))
{
    var department = group.Key;
    var email = group.First().Email;
    var body = string.Join(", ", group.Select(x => x.Product));

    SendMail(email, department, body);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you may use the grouping for the task.

```
var groups = test.GroupBy(x => x.Email);
foreach (var group in groups)
{
  var email = group.Key; // Exactly the property from GroupBy
  var goods = group.Select(x => x.Good); // Donut, Bagel, Cake...
  var body = string.Join(", ", goods);

  // Now you can send the email with body containing "Donut, Bagel. Cake"
}
```

Each instance of the `group` variable contains `Key` property and the collection of grouped items from the `test` collection.

Thus, you can use the `group` either with methods like `Select`, or with the `foreach` operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *group* (items) let's `GroupBy` (by `Department` and `Address`).
First, let's prepare the data:

```
var emails = test
  .GroupBy(item => (department : item.Department, address : item.Address),
           item => item.Item)
  .Select(group => (department : group.Key.department,
                    address    : group.Key.address,
                    body       : string.Join(", ", group.Distinct().OrderBy(item => item))));
```

then we are ready to send mails:

```
foreach (var letter in emails)
  SendEmail(letter.address, letter.deparment, letter.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that all `tests` with department `Bakery` have the same e-mail address? Or could it be (for instance, due to typing errors) some Bakeries have a different e-mail address?

If all Bakeries have the same address, then you could use one of the overloads of [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-7.0) to make groups of tests that have the same department. Then for every group take the e-mail of the first test in the group (or any other, they are all the same anyway). Use the overload with the parameter `resultselector` to specify your result

```
class Test
{
    public string Department {get; set;}
    public string EmailAddress {get; set;}
    ... // other properties
}

IEnumerable<Test> myTests = ...

var departmentsEmailAddresses = myTests.GroupBy(

    // make groups of test that have the same value for Department
    test => test.Department,

    // parameter resultSelector: for every Department name and all Tests that have
    // this value for Department name, make one new object:
    (department, testsWithThisValueForDepartment) => new
    {
        // if desired: remember the department name
        Department = department,

        // to get the e-mail address, take the first test.
        // BTW: all tests in this group will have the same e-mail address
        Email = testsWithThisValueForDepartment.Select(test => test.EmailAddress)
                                               .FirstOrDefault(),
    })
```

In words: for all tests, make groups of tests that have the same value for property `Department`. Every group will at least have one test in it. From every group, take the common value for `Department` that all tests in this group will have. Furthermore, take the tests in this group, and select the value of `EmailAddress`. Only do this for the first test in the group.

The result will be a sequence of combinations of `[Department, Email]`